# sturm-liouville differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sturm-liouville

I need method to find the values of $\lambda$

$$1.-y''+x^2 y=\lambda y$$
 $$2. -y''+|x| y=\lambda y$$
$$ 3. -y''+(x^2 +x^4) y=\lambda y$$

with initial condition $y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$

Comment: The first one is Schrodinger's equation for a simple harmonic oscillator, so you can get the eigenvalues (odd positive integers) in a slick way via annihilation and creation operators. For the second you want the zeros of the first derivative of an Airy function, but the third doesn't have a closed from solution like that. I assume that you are to find all the eigenvalues numerically? Which numerical method have you discussed that would be suitable?